# Redirect Using PHP Method Chaining?

Tags: php, redirect

Let's say we want to redirect a user to a form page with some errors after submitting. I have this method in my controller.

```
return redirect('create')->withErrors($errors)->withInputs($inputs);
```

Now I have a helper function named redirect which returns a new Redirect object.

```
function redirect($fileName)
{
 return new Redirect($fileName);
}
```

and here is the sturcture of Redirect class

```
class Redirect
{

  public function __construct($fileName)
  {
    header("Location: " . $fileName);

    return $this;
  }


  public function withErros($errors)
  {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;

    return $this;
  }



  public function withInputs($inputs)
  {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION('inputs') = $inputs;

    return $this;
  }
}
```

The first chaining method (`withErrors`) runs correctly and I can show errors in my view. But the second one (`withInputs`) never runs. I think it's because of header function in PHP. 
Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Then it's `$_SESSION['inputs']`

Comment: `withErros` should be `withErrors`.

Comment: No, it was just a typo when I typed it here.

Comment: Check your error log for `Headers already sent` warning.

Comment: You are redirecting within `__construct`, so the behavior of PHP will be unkown. And returnnig $this is not needed in a constructor.

Comment: and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Redirect
{
  protected $filename;
  public function __construct($fileName)
  {
      session_start();
      $this->filename=$filename;
  }
  public function __destruct()
  {
      $this->redirect();
  }
  public function withErros($errors)
  {
      $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
      return $this;
  }
  public function withInputs($inputs)
  {
      $_SESSION('inputs') = $inputs;
      return $this;
  }
  public function redirect(){
      header("Location: " . $this->filename);
      exit;
  }
}
```

This can be a solution.